# Xcode 15.0 beta 6 build errors

Tags: ios, xcode

**Chip: Apple M1 Pro**

- In Xcode 15 beta 6, this error occurs when compiling for the simulator. But everything works fine in Xcode 14.
- The Excluded Architectures option has been modified in the Build Setting (target & pods), the Any iOS Simulator SDK option has been added, and the value is set to arm64.

##### Errors Message:

Showing All Errors Only
Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file (/Users/xxx/x/xxx/iOS/Pods/DmpPlayer/Libraries/libDmpPlayer.a[x86_64]598) built for 'iOS'
[image]
[image]